# Get a JS Variable out of a Function (Geocode)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoder

I want to get the var `lat` and `lng` out of the function, to use it in var `bounds` later.
Is the use of the `return` statement correct?
The code at the bottom does not change the var `bounds` for some reason.

Still do not get it to work. I am really sorry for wasting your time...

```
function foo(bounds){
if(bounds = "((1,180), (-1,-180))"){
    bounds ="";
    var address = "<?php echo $_GET['SuchePlz']; ?>";
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var lat =results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var lng =results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            bounds = lat;

        } 
        else {
         alert(address + ' not found');
        }
     return bounds;
    });

       }
else{"";}
}

       bounds = foo();
```

Comment: you can use bounds inside callback directly

Comment: I tried that! But if I do so it does not alert the changed var 'bounds'